# Sincronização BD MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sincronização

Bom dia,
Sobre sincronização de dados MySql onde tenha o servidor Master e o servidor Slave, gostaria de saber se é possível eu ter vários master para um único slave, onde os master sincronizariam com o slave inserindo dados e buscando dados dos outros bancos no slave. 
Preciso disso para o seguinte cenário: Temos várias empresas em diferente localidade e cada empresa vai ter o seu banco de dados local que deverá enviar as inserções/alterações feitas e receber as alterações das outras filiais, onde teria um BD que ficaria responsável por ter todas as informações e compartilhas com as demais.

Comment: Melhor fazer essa pergunta nesse [site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) voltada para essas dúvidas e problemas.

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer isso. Obrigada!